# Binding in a DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a List and want to bind it to a DataGrid.
Here is my Code-Behind:

```
public ManageParties(CtContainerDescription description)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<CtParty> ctParties = description.GetAssociatedParties();
        PartyDataGrid.ItemsSource = ctParties;
    }
```

Note that CtParty is not part of the same class, but the Resource is included via `using`. It has the fields "Name" and "Description".
And here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PartyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HeadersVisibility="All">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Edit"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The behaviour I receive is that I get the right amount of rows, but the content of the cells are empty.

I already tried different things:

- Adding `ItemsSource={Binding}` in the DataGrid XAML
- Added `DataContext={Binding CtParty}`
- Used `{Binding Path=Name}` etc.
- Setting `PartiesDataGrid.DataContext = ctParties;`

Am I missing something obvious?
Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Make sure that Name and Description are public properties of the CtParty class. Data binding only works with public properties, not with fields.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess this is the problem then. Need to find a workaround then!